# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape

Tags: opencv, image-processing

How can I get the height and width values, I keep getting error about the shape attribute

```
import cv2

img_path = cv2.imread('6.jpg')
image = cv2.imread(img_path)
h, w = img_path.shape[:2]
```

Comment: remove the `image = cv2.imread(img_path)` line. You read the image only once and then it becomes an object and you can't use `cv2.imread()` on an object.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I removed the `image = cv2.imread(img_path)` line as you said but it's still giving the me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the `image = cv2.imread(img_path)` line. You read the image only once and then it becomes an object and you can't use `cv2.imread()` on an object. After doing this there error is still there then it means that your image is not in the same folder where the kernel is running from. You can check this using

```
import os
os.path.exists('6.jpg') # Will likely give False
os.getcwd() # This will return the current working directory
```

After this check, you will likely get false. Now you should look at the relative path of your image from your current working directory and pass that path into your `cv2.imread()`.